# Umbraco, adding attachments to articles in back-end and then showing them in front-end CMS

Tags: umbraco

On my Umbraco website, I have the section which shows latest News. Each news is one article.

Unfortunately, I can't add any attachments to any News article in back-end so users could see that attachment(s) on front-end of website and download them if they want to. This is how I it should look like

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/895x383q90/826/cozp.jpg

Is this possible to do? While I was using Joomla CMS it was very easy by installing additional module/component which took me only 15 minutes to set.

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance for prompt replies!
MC2012

Answer (score 1):

The solution is fairly simple:

1. Add the attachments to a folder in the 'Media' section
2. Add a field to the document type that the page uses called 'attachments' and use the datatype 'Multi-node Picker'
3. On the page content pick the attachments you are interested in
4. Render the list of attachments (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ucomponents/questionssuggestions/26638-Multi-Node-Tree-Picker-help-with-example-code-(in-Razor))
   using something like:

   ```
   <article>
       @if(Model.HasValue("attachments")){
       <ul>
           @foreach(var item in Model.attachments){
           var node = Library.NodeById(item.InnerText);
           <li>
               <a href="@node.Url" title="@node.Name">@node.Name</a>
           </li>                                           
           }
       </ul>                           
       }
   </article>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for fast answer. However, in the meantime I have find solution. Here is the link

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/47616-Adding-attachments-to-articles-in-back-end-and-then-showing-them-in-front-end-CMS

I hope someone else will have some use of it because it is great solution.

BR,
MC2012